# Unity 2D, Changing the direction of a moving object

Tags: 3d, 2d

```
    randomX = Random.Range(-1f, 1f);
    randomY = Random.Range(-1f, 1f);

    dir = new Vector2(randomX, randomY).normalized;

    rb.velocity = (dir * speed)
```

(There may be typos because I can't speak English and upload it using a translator.)

My game object, the ball, uses Rigidbody 2D and the ball moves using Velocity. (Speed variable is 3f)
I've written various functions about rotation, but only the game object rotates, and the direction of movement remains the same.
How can I change the direction of movement?
(My goal is to change the direction of movement of the ball by 90 degrees (see photo))

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lN19S.png)

Comment: By direction of the game object what do you mean? the rotation?

Comment: It's hard to understand the question. The direction of the game object is the direction of movement Rotation is just a spinning game object.